# Resize an image when software keyboard opens

Tags: android

I have a login activity which has `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` set to fit login fields when keyboard appears. I want an image that is above the fields to get smaller so it wouldn't overlap with the login fields.

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/et_email"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_foreground" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/et_password"/>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_password" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_remind_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn_login"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Post your layout for a full answer.  But the basic answer is-  use a RelativeLayout or Constraint Layout so that the image is told to go above the input fields, and then when it gets resized it will stay above the input fields but with less room.

Comment: @GabeSechan the image gets stretched this way. Updated the post with layout.

Comment: Don't use fit xy scale type. That doesn't preserve aspect ratio

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks! Just what I wanted!